# Doctrine Configuration (doctrine.yaml) when creating modules in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created multiple modules folder inside my symfony project. Therefore each Entity and it's Repository class are kept in their own module folder instead keeping them in default `src/Entity` folder like this.

```
src
 - Post
   - Persistence
       - Entity
           - Post.php
       - Repository
           - PostRepository.php
 - PostComment
   - Persistence
       - Entity
           - PostComment.php
       - Repository
           - PostCommentRepository.php
```

Now to make this work in `conig/doctrine.yaml`, I had to create multiple `entity_managers` like this

```
orm:
        entity_managers:
            vouchers:
                mappings:
                    Post:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: attribute
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Modules/Post/Persistence/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Modules\Post\Persistence\Entity'
                        alias: Post
                    PostComment:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: attribute
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Modules/PostComment/Persistence/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Modules\PostComment\Persistence\Entity'
                        alias: PostComment
```

**This works however** as you noticed, this makes me create new entity manager line in the `doctrine.yaml` configuration file every time I add new entity. There are going to more than 100 tables and I don't feel this is a right way to do it even though it works.

**Question: Is there a way to make this dynamic so that I don't need to repeat myself?**

More or less, I was hoping it would support regex like this but of-course this does not work.

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Modules/*/Persistence/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Modules\*\Persistence\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: Theoretically anything in a folder not marked with an `Entity` attribute would be ignored. So if you put the path on Modules it should pick up everything under it.

However I don't know if that has any major performance impact. Alternatively in a compiler pass you could add the mapping with a loop from some glob results.

Comment: One approach would be to use xml mapping.  All the mapping files could be in one directory even if the entities are scattered across multiple namespaces.  Of course most developers seem to prefer using annotation/attributes for mapping.  Another approach would be to add a bundle class to each module and add the class to config/bundles.php.  Bit extreme perhaps.

Comment: And should every table really be it's own module?  Seems like related entities could share the same module.  I would make a fake directory structure showing your completed app and make sure your proposed approach really makes sense and that you are not making life more difficult than it needs to be.  Maybe try thinking in terms of organizing by features instead of entities.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, You are right, each table does not deserves its own module folder. Using that approach, I can come down to 20 or so modules, still some duplication but its not that bad.